# Testing abstract class with static properties

Tags: php, testing, laravel, phpspec

I'm new to testing and I'm using phpspec to test a service class which validates input. I'm not sure how to test the class because it uses `static::$base_rules` and `static::$create_rules`. Those values are determined by the child class extending `Acme\Services\Validation\Validator`.

I realize I'm doing things a little backwards with phpspec, but I wanted to practice with this established class and I'm not sure if it's possible or if my `Acme\Services\Validation\Validator` class is poorly coded.

**Class I want to test with phpspec**

```
<?php namespace Acme\Services\Validation;

use Illuminate\Validation\Factory as Validation;

abstract class Validator
{

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $rules;

    /**
     * @var object
     */
    protected $validation;

    /**
     * @var Validator
     */
    private $validator;

    /**
     * @param Validation $validator
     */
    public function __construct(Validation $validator)
    {
        $this->rules = isset(static::$base_rules) ? static::$base_rules : [];
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }

    /**
     * @param $input
     * @return \Illuminate\Validation\Validator
     */
    public function validateCreateRules($input)
    {
        $rules = array_merge(static::$create_rules, $this->rules);

        return $this->validate($input, $rules);
    }

    /**
     * @param $input
     * @param $rules
     * @return \Illuminate\Validation\Validator
     * @throws FormValidationException
     */
    public function validate($input, $rules)
    {
        $this->validation = $this->validator->make($input, $rules);

        if ($this->validation->fails())
        {
            throw new FormValidationException('Validation failed', $this->getValidationErrors());
        }
        return $this->validation;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getValidationErrors()
    {
        return $this->validation->errors();
    }
}
```

**Here's an example class that extends Validator**

```
<?php namespace Acme\Services\Validation;

class MessageValidator extends Validator {

    static $base_rules = array(
        'type'              => 'required',
        'title'             => 'required',
        'message'           => 'required'
    );

    static $create_rules = array(
        'user'              => 'required'
    );

}
```

How could `Acme\Services\Validation\Validator` be tested using phpspec?

Comment: Don't tests abstracts, test concretes

Comment: Doesn't that create a lot of duplication with all of my other Validation classes that extend Validator?

Comment: As you can't instantiate an abstract, you can't test methods in an abstract without creating a concrete class to test them... perhaps have a simple concrete class that extends your abstract purely for testing those methods if you don't want to duplicate tests

Comment: I would use Laravel's IoC/Facades functionality to avoid the static stuff altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll ignore the use of statics...

As others already suggested you should spec concrete implementations. You could provide one just for the purpose of speccing (for example if you only provide the abstract class for others to use).

You'll have to tell phpspec to use the concrete implementation instead of the abstract class:

```php
$this->beAnInstanceOf('My\Not\Abstract\Implementation');
```